# Collection type inline template

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony4, sonata, symfony-sonata

I'd like to create a custom template for my inline collection because inline isn't suitable. I'm struggling to figure out how to get a custom template to render.

I tried adding a template and then using `template` as an attribute on the field which didn't work.

```
->add('pictures', CollectionType::class, [
    'by_reference' => false,
    'label' => false,
], [
    'edit' => 'inline',
    'inline' => 'table',
    'template' => 'admin/picture/test.html.twig'
])
```

*My templates for custom admin edits etc site in templates/admin/..*

I also added the method `getFormTheme()` to the admin the collection uses and added a dump and die to see if it gets called and it doesn't dump and die.

```
// PicutreAdmin.php

public function getFormTheme()
{
    return array_merge(parent::getFormTheme(), [
        'admin/picture/test.html.twig'
    ]);
}
```

Note I want this template to only apply to this particular collection and none of the other collections I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can override admin template like shown here https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html extend it and use strategy described here https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/form/form_customization.html on How to Customize an individual Field

But be aware that Sonata adds custom prefix to all form element names so you have to figure out how that collection is named, you can do that by debugging form blocks and this article might help you https://blog.bouzekri.net/2015-02-06-symfony-tips-find-form-theme-override-block-name.html